# Find ALL the supervisors (direct and indirect) of Bob?

Tags: oracle

Im learning about Oracle db and i have this question in my book :

[here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYQrl.png)

so the third note:

Find ALL the supervisors (direct and indirect) of Bob ??

the solution in book like this :

```
select distinct s.super_name,t.super_name from emp_super s * emp_super t where 
s.super_name = t.person_name ;
```

can any one explain this to me ? i dont understand this solution ?
and any other solution for this ?

> Note: my db is oracle .

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a hierarchical query. Would this do?

```
SQL> with test (person, supervisor) as
  2    (select 'bob', 'alice'   from dual union all
  3     select 'mary', 'susan'  from dual union all
  4     select 'alice', 'david' from dual union all
  5     select 'david', 'mary'  from dual
  6    )
  7  select sys_connect_by_path(supervisor, '->') sv
  8  from test
  9  start with person = 'bob'
 10  connect by person = prior supervisor;

SV
---------------------------------------------------------------------
->alice
->alice->david
->alice->david->mary
->alice->david->mary->susan

SQL>
```

It *starts with* "Bob" (as you said that it should), and *connects* every person with their supervisor (i.e. specifies relationship between parent and child rows in the hierarchy). More about hierarchical queries [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

As of the "solution" you posted: well, it is invalid (instead of `*` there should have been a `,`; but, then again, you'd rather use ANSI JOIN). When it is fixed, it just returns all rows except the first one in your table, so I'm not sure *why* they call it a "solution".

It joins the same table twice, so it is called a *self-join*.

Answer (score 1):

I am supposing that you have the following table created with you.

[image]

We are going to use the concept of creating a cartesian product as it will contain all the possible combinations.

The tested code is given below:

```
select t.supervisor from empsuper as s, empsuper as t where s.supervisor=t.person;
```

The output to it will be:

[image]

This is the required output according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct s.super_name,t.super_name from emp_super s * 
emp_super t where 
s.super_name = t.person_name ;
```

**This solution will give only two levels of employees**

Here when you use * in after from, (you should use a ',' actually), you are actually taking a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two tables( Here Both tables are the same). Also, s and t represent the same tables. Suppose this is the table:
[image]

Cartesian Product of this table with itself:

[image]

Cartesian Product of this table with itself with the condition that s.supervisor=t.person:

[image]

Now, We can see how it gives us the direct and indirect employees.

Answer (score 0):

```
select supervisor from emp_super where person='Bob'
UNION
select supervisor from emp_super where person in ( select supervisor from emp_super where person='Bob')
UNION
select supervisor from emp_super where person in (select supervisor from emp_super where person in ( select supervisor from emp_super where person='Bob')
)
UNION
select supervisor from emp_super where person in ( select supervisor from emp_super where person in (select supervisor from emp_super where person in ( select supervisor from emp_super where person='Bob')))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. However, code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers with an explanation are always more helpful. Though the solution may be obvious to you, to others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from other answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).